# Reading and changing objects in .yaml file (Using PyYAML)

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I looked around for hours, couldn't get anything more than a broad introduction. It implied I knew a lot more than I do.

```
main:
    user-settings:
        accountID: 666
        timestamp: 00:00
    client settings:
        nickname: "mainPC"
        region: "OK"
```

How do I print "accountID" and "region" for example?

If I wanted to change the accountID from 666 to 102, how would I do that?

Comment: There is a question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186653/pyyaml-saving-data-to-yaml-files) with example code of how to handle this.

Comment: What do you suppose would be the result of calling `accountID`? After loading `accountId` is key in Python `dict`, not something that is callable. What do you mean with changing the `accountId`. You want to change the key and keep the same value, or do you want to change the value associated with the key in that mapping (if so you should state that in a non-ambiguous way).

Comment: @Anthon Made it clearer. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really do what you ask for in PyYAML, not even for the small
example that you have. Printing the requested value works, but when you update
your YAML you'll see that it changes several of the output lines in
addition to the value for `accountID`. Assuming your YAML file is
`test.yaml`:

```
from pathlib import Path
import yaml

yaml_file = Path('test.yaml')

with yaml_file.open() as fp:
    data = yaml.safe_load(fp)
user_settings = data['main']['user-settings']
print('acount id:', user_settings['accountID'])
user_settings['accountID'] = 102
print('region:   ', data['main']['client settings']['region'])

with yaml_file.open('w') as fp:
    yaml.safe_dump(data, fp, indent=4, default_flow_style=False)
```

this outputs:

```
acount id: 666
region:    OK
```

And the contents of `test.yaml` will be:

```
main:
    client settings:
        nickname: mainPC
        region: OK
    user-settings:
        accountID: 102
        timestamp: 00:00
```

You get you a Python `dict` for any mapping in the YAML file, and a
Python `list` if you would have had a sequence in your YAML. To print a
value that you want, you just traverse the nested `dict`s.

As you can see you loose the quotes arround `OK` and `mainPC` and you
gain them around `00:00`. The latter is because PyYAML has not been
updated to process the current YAML 1.2 standard released back in
2009. In YAML 1.1, scalars of the form XX:YY are assumed to be
[sexagesimals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal) and
converted (and dumped) as integers (or floats if there had been a
decimal point). That your `00:00` is loaded as a string is because of
the leading zero. If it had been `12:00`, then your output file would
be `timestamp: 720`.

The order of the keys in your mapping is also not
preserved. Semantically this makes no difference, but if this file is
under revision control, such changes quickly becomming confusing.

You should use `safe_load()`, as the "standard" `load()` can be unsafe
on uncontrolled YAML input, and although documented, most people don't
realise this, nor that it is essentially never necessary. (Unsafe as
in "harddrive wiped", or worse.)

---

If you want to update a YAML file, I recommend using
[`ruamel.yaml`](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (disclaimer: I
am the author of that package).

```
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_file = Path('test.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_file)

user_settings = data['main']['user-settings']
print('acount id:', user_settings['accountID'])
user_settings['accountID'] = 102
print('region:   ', data['main']['client settings']['region'])

yaml.dump(data, yaml_file)
```

which also outputs:

```
acount id: 666
region:    OK
```

And the contents of `test.yaml` will be:

```
main:
    user-settings:
        accountID: 102
        timestamp: 00:00
    client settings:
        nickname: "mainPC"
        region: "OK"
```

Not only are the quotes properly preserved, but it doesn't have to
quote `00:00`, because `ruamel.yaml` handles YAML 1.2 in which
sexagesimals are dropped altogether¹. The order of the keys in mappings
is preserved.

If there would have been comments in `test.yaml`, then  `PyYAML` would have discarded these,
whereas `ruamel.yaml` preserve these as well.

In `ruamel.yaml`, the default `YAML()` uses a safe loader.

---

¹<sub>You can still use sexagesimals if you create a `Sexagesimal`
class and tag them appropriately. In that case you can also decide to
have leading zero's (`!sexagesimal 00:00`), and properly dump these values
back as tagged, non-quoted, scalars.</sub>